# Why is the Azure Logic app HTTP module modifying the response payload?

Tags: azure, http, logic, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to fetch data from a ticketing system with logic app, using the built-in HTTP module.

When testing with postman, I get the following response:

```
GET: https://ticketsystem/api/ticket/{{number}}

{
"tickets": [
    {
        "links": {
            "data1": {
                "id": 4
            },
            "data2": {
                "id": 3
            },
            "data3": {
                "id": 969
            }
            ...
        },
        "data1Id": 4,
        "data2Id": 3,
        "data3Id": 969,
        "att1": 1,
        "att1": 2,
        "att1": 3,
        "att1": 4
        ....
    }
]}
```

But, when trying through the HTTP logic app module, this is the response:

```
{
    "data1Id": 4,
    "data2Id": 3,
    "data3Id": 969,
    "att1": 1,
    "att1": 2,
    "att1": 3,
    "att1": 4
    ...
}
```

Everything else is the same, I have even tried in a new logic app and a totally different azure account. It is still the same.

I've looked through the http header response, and there are some differences.

**Postman:**

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Expires: -1
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-PS-ActionTime: 00:00:00.0022451
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
Date: Wed, 16 Jun 2021 09:41:50 GMT
Content-Length: 819
```

**Azure HTTP:**

```
"Pragma": "no-cache",
"Vary": "Accept-Encoding",
"X-PS-ActionTime": "00:00:00.0022021",
"X-Frame-Options": "deny",
"X-XSS-Protection": "1; mode=block",
"Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload",
"Cache-Control": "no-cache",
"Date": "Wed, 16 Jun 2021 09:43:27 GMT",
"Server": "Microsoft-IIS/10.0",
"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
"Expires": "-1",
"Content-Length": "1733"
```

It looks like the "Content-Encoding: gzip" is missing from logic app, but I do not know why this is affecting the overall response structure. Also how to fix this issue.

I have tried to enable "Allow chunking", without any luck.

I understand that I might create an Azure Function to go around this, but I'm trying to avoid that for now.

Any advice?

**EDIT**

I tested with powershell Invoke-WebRequest, and I see that this is behaving the same as the Logic app HTTP action.
From powershell, the header is also the same (missing Content-Encoding: gzip) and the "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8"

But, when testing with python (3.9) with the request module, then it's spitting out the same data as postman.

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

I am really trying to understand the difference here on the header level, as this is the only difference between the responses, and also what application/vnd.api+json and Content-Encoding: gzip does here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sovled it.

I simply put this as a header on the HTTP Action:

```
"Accept": "application/vnd.api+json; charset=utf-8"
```

And the response message was the same as in Postman.

This still does not answer *why* it is behaving differently, since none of the request headers had this value in all of the metodes I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http#omitted-http-headers

[image]

I see a feedback for this too: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/42578674-enable-support-for-content-type-header-in-http-get

Comment: I do not see that any of the headers I have provided, are in the omitted http headers.